# Splitting SQL result into groups with max size = n

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table

```
 id | volume_id| ... |
----+----------+-----+
  1 |       1  | ... |
  2 |       2  | ... |
  3 |       1  | ... |
  4 |       3  | ... |
  5 |       2  | ... |
  ...
```

I can do a simple grouping query:

```
select volume_id, count(*), min(id) as min_id, max(id) as max_id
from my_table
group by volume_id;
```

Which will produce result:

```
 volume_id | count | min_id | max_id    
-----------+-------+--------+--------
         1 | 67330 |  ...   | ...
         2 | 67330 |  ...   | ...
         3 | 67330 |  ...   | ...
         4 | 67330 |  ...   | ...
```

But I would like to split results into groups of 40K rows. So the results should look like:

```
 volume_id | count | min_id | max_id    
-----------+-------+--------+--------
         1 | 40000 |  ...   | ...      <- first  group of IDs for volume 1
         1 | 27330 |  ...   | ...      <- second group of IDs for volume 1
         2 | 40000 |  ...   | ...
         2 | 27330 |  ...   | ...
         3 | 40000 |  ...   | ...
         4 | 27330 |  ...   | ...
```

ID's should be split so that `max_id` for first group should be smaller than `min_id` from second group and so on.

If any one has idea how to write such query (or plsql function if there is no other way), I would be grateful.

I am using Postgresql 9.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rank()` (or `row_number()` if there are no duplicates) to enumerate the groups.  Then simple arithmetic in the `group by`:

```
select volume_id, count(*), min(id) as min_id, max(id) as max_id
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by volume_id order by id) as seqnum
      from my_table t
     ) t
group by volume_id, floor((seqnum - 1) / 40000)
order by volume_id, min(id);
```

Comment: Wow, nice tempo! Only small improvement: should be `*` instead of `t.*`. Beside that works great!